# Simple Opengl and Graphics Questions

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d

1. Is COP and the "Camera" the same thing? Which in turn refers to the "User" looking at the screen?
2. Can someone please explain to me the relation between the Projection Perspective and the Viewport if there is one? Because at the moment to me they seem to be the same thing. Or is the PP the Window which is then scaled to fit the viewport?
3. In OpenGL when setting up gluPerspective the zNear value is the distance of the Camera from the Projection Perspective so the combination of the fovy and zNear defines the size of the Window (assuming that the Window == the Projection Perspective and I undestand something :/ ) into the World.
4. When creating a window (only using gl and glu), after you have initalized everything you enter while(!quit) loop that has a render function(this is question is a bit silly), does everything in all case get drawn in this render function which has glBegin() and glEnd(). Lets assume I have a biggish world with lots of features and so on. Does everything that needs to get drawn fit in between those functions such that this Render function can in time become really large?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is COP and the "Camera" the same thing? Which in turn refers to the "User" looking at the screen?

COP can mean a lot, but I assume you mean "Center of Projection". In the case of a affine projection, the COP is indeed at the location of the "camera". However OpenGL does not have a camera, and the COP usually is located at the origin. Moving the "camera" happens by moving the whole world opposite to how you'd move the camera.

> Can someone please explain to me the relation between the Projection Perspective and the Viewport if there is one?

Projection Perspective is sort of a "lens" you attach to the camera. You could also use a entirely different projection, which behaves very differently.

The Viewport is the portion of your window to which the projection boundaries are "aligned". Imagine the Viewport being the part of the window/screen onto which you place/scale/strech the rendered picture (of course the rendering happens directly to the viewport).

> Because at the moment to me they seem to be the same thing. Or is the PP the Window which is then scaled to fit the viewport?

It's more like the later.

> In OpenGL when setting up gluPerspective the zNear value is the distance of the Camera from the Projection Perspective so the combination of the fovy and zNear defines the size of the Window (assuming that the Window == the Projection Perspective and I undestand something :/ ) into the World.

Not quite. The projection volume is defined by a so called frustum (a four sided pyramid of which you've cut the tip). The tip is at the origin, i.e. everything gets projected toward the tip. But the plane on which things are projected is the near plane. It's easy to see, that the near plane should be as far away from the origin as possible and the far plane as near as possible. Also the must both have the same sign, otherwise things get projected "through" the origin which looks just wrong.

> When creating a window (only using gl and glu),

You can't create a window with just OpenGL and GLU (GLU is not part of OpenGL BTW!).

> after you have initalized everything you enter while(!quit) loop that has a render function(this is question is a bit silly), does everything in all case get drawn in this render function which has glBegin() and glEnd(). Lets assume I have a biggish world with lots of features and so on. Does everything that needs to get drawn fit in between those functions such that this Render function can in time become really large?

Well, OpenGL is not a scene graph. It's a drawing API as you already figured out. And yes, everything that should be on screen must be put into the drawing function. However you will never place your scene directly into code. You build some abstract data structures, which you fill with data from an external source and then have a set of render functions, that iterate through those structures to decide, what to render and make the right drawing calls.

BTW: Immediate mode, i.e. `glBegin` … `glEnd` has been deprecated since OpenGL-2 in favour of Vertex Arrays. Please don't use immediate mode. Just skip every chapter and tutorial about it.